# I don't know why this error message appears. jQuery / html. Passing variable into DIV

Tags: jquery, html

I keep receiving this error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )' when I run this piece of code.

```
var strongName = "Joe";

function createTopReport(pageDiv) {
    pageDiv.append($('<div>').addClass('content').append(
    $('<span>').addClass('ui-reports-to').append(
    $('<div>').addClass('ui-reports-to-text').html('Reports to ')).append(
    $('<img>').addClass('ui-green-icon-image').attr('src', "{! URLFOR($Resource.image)}")).append(
    $('<span>').addClass('ui-r-name').html(strongName);) < --ERROR POINTS TO THIS BRACKET))
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about typos with parenthesis.

Comment: Well I didn't know what was causing the error. I thought it might have been more than a typo. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
).append(
    $('<span>').addClass('ui-r-name').html(strongName);
)
```

Remove the semicolon

Comment: Cheers James Montagne!

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the semicolon `;` inside the `append` method:

```
).append(
   $('<span>').addClass('ui-r-name').html(strongName); // <-- Remove this semicolon
)
```

which is causing the error like:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;